# Sharepoint trigger a javascript on anchor to remove attachment

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I want to trigger the javascript "RemoveLocal("attachRow1","fileupload1")" on the anchor on code below,

```
<span class="ms-delAttachments">
  <img src="/_layouts/15/images/rect.gif?rev=44">
  <a href='javascript:RemoveLocal("attachRow1","fileupload1")'>Delete</a>
</span>
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use an `onclick` event to trigger the function call.

```
<span class="ms-delAttachments">
  <img src="/_layouts/15/images/rect.gif?rev=44">
  <button onclick="RemoveLocal('attachRow1','fileupload1')">Delete</button>
</span>
```

Comment: Not. its build by SharePoint, not create by me. I can only customize the javascript action.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solve.

$(".ms-delAttachments a")[0].click();